# Curvature of helix Find the curvature of the helix r(t)= 3cost(i)+3sint(j)+5t(k)

Tags: calculus

Find the curvature for the helix r(t)= 3cost(i)+3sint(j)+5t(k)

I am preety sure the answer is 3/25, but I am not able to understand the exact way to solve this problem.Please help!!

Comment: Do you know the formula for curvature?

Comment: Yeah but I am stuck with the process can't really understand it :/

Comment: At what point of the process are you stuck? The first step is to find $r'$. Can you do that? Then there's the second step...

Comment: Is the final step (a^2+b^2)/2 ?

Comment: I don't know what a and b you are talking about. The second step is to divide $r'$ by its magnitude. This gives you T, the unit tangent. Then you take the derivative of that with respect to arclength; it helps that r is parametrized proportional to arclength.

Comment: Or you may be using a *different* formula, which does not assume arclength parametrization. This is why I asked you if you know the formula to use. You should *edit* your question to say what you know and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

If $r(t)=(3\cos t,3\sin t, 5t)$ the curvature is

$$\kappa  = \frac{|r' \times r''|}{|r'|^3}$$

Then

$r'(t)=(-3\sin t, 3\cos t, 5)$

$r''(t)=(-3\cos t,-3\sin t, 0)$

Therefore
$$\kappa  = \frac{|(-3\sin t, 3\cos t, 5)\times (-3\cos t,-3\sin t, 0)|}{|(-3\sin t, 3\cos t, 5)|^3}$$

$$\kappa  = \frac{|(15\sin t, -15\cos t, 9) |}{|(-3\sin t, 3\cos t, 5)|^3}=\frac{|3(5\sin t, -5\cos t, 3) |}{|(-3\sin t, 3\cos t, 5)|^3}=\frac{3\sqrt{34}}{(\sqrt{34})^3}=\frac{3}{34}.$$

In general for the helix $r(t)=(a\cos t,a\sin t, bt)$ the curvature is $\kappa=\frac{a}{b^2+a^2}$.